Scipy returns error when given an SHGO optimization problem
Following the paragraph "Global optimization" in this page, I run the following code
from scipy import optimize
from math import log

bounds = [(0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]

def some_function(u_1, w_1, u_2, w_2):
    return log(1+u_1)/(1+w_1) + log(1+u_2)/(1+w_2)

optimize.shgo(some_function, bounds)

I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marc/PythonEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo_lib/_complex.py", line 499, in refine
    next(self.rls)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marc/Documents/virer/OptimizationWithConstraints.py", line 25, in <module>
    optimize.shgo(some_function, bounds)
  File "/home/marc/PythonEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo.py", line 455, in shgo
    shc.iterate_all()
  File "/home/marc/PythonEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo.py", line 836, in iterate_all
    self.iterate()
  File "/home/marc/PythonEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo.py", line 1009, in iterate
    self.iterate_complex()
  File "/home/marc/PythonEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo.py", line 1033, in iterate_hypercube
    self.HC.refine(self.n)
  File "/home/marc/PythonEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo_lib/_complex.py", line 501, in refine
    vp = self.triangulated_vectors[0]
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Have I done something wrong?

Bounds should be (min,max) pairs for each argument

With bounds = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)] I get TypeError: some_function() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'w_1', 'u_2', and 'w_2'

Here is a syntax which works:
from scipy import optimize
from math import log

bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))

def some_function(x):
    return log(1+x[0])/(1+x[1]) + log(1+x[2])/(1+x[3])

results = dict()
print(optimize.shgo(some_function, bounds))

